# Change WP All Import script to import the newest XML from FTP

Tags: wordpress, import, ftp, php-curl, wpallimport

I would like to use this script to download the XML feed which is updated every 20 min.
The problem is the file name has a date and time stamp. 
Can someone point me in the right direction how to change it so it will always picks the newest file so i can update the stock.

Sample file names:

Feed2842020175940.xml

Feed2842020173907.xml

Feed2842020171807.xml

Calling the function from the 'Download from URL' option on Step 1:

```
[custom_file_download("ftp://username:password@hostname.com/path/to/file.xml","xml")]
```

Function itself:

```
// Programmatically download and return import file via URL.
function custom_file_download($url, $type = 'xml'){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
    /* Optional: Set headers...
    *    $headers = array();
    *    $headers[] = "Accept-Language: de";
    *    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    */
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
            exit('Error:' . curl_error($ch));
    }
    curl_close ($ch);
    $uploads = wp_upload_dir();
    $filename = $uploads['basedir'] . '/' . strtok(basename($url), "?") . '.' . $type;
    if (file_exists($filename)){
            @unlink($filename);
    }
    file_put_contents($filename, $result);
    return str_replace($uploads['basedir'], $uploads['baseurl'], $filename);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two ways to do this:

1. Have a logic on the server with the XML files where the newest file will always have the same name (e.g. `latest.xml`). You could probably achieve this by using symbolic links.
2. Work back from the current timestamp (i.e. using `time()` or another way to get a timestamp in the format the filenames are using) to deduce the latest filename on the server. I don't see how else this can be done except to decrement the timestamp by 1 then check if a file with that timestamp in the name exists, then decrement by 1 again and check, etc. This option is **not** a good idea. :)